# Recycler view last item get truncated

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

It looks like my layouting is bad.
So I have a recycler view and the top app bar inside constraint layout (for positioning). And I have a swipe refresh as container. But when I run my app, the last item of recycler view is not show fully (get cut/truncated)

[image]

Here is my xml layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".view.ThirdScreen">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rv_user">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/material_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_ios_24"
            app:navigationIconTint="#554AF0"
            app:title="Third Screen"
            app:titleCentered="true"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Add in your RecyclerView XML this 2 lines android:clipToPadding="false", and android:paddingBottom="20dp"

Comment: @MokhtarAbdelhalim Thanks man, appreciate it, somehow it works. But it needs like 60dp padding bottom to fully shown the last item